# How do I set the graph to have this shape?

Tags: graph-editor

[image: F-Curve with overlay showing desired shape]

Currently the graph is set to "Ease in and out". I'd like to obtain the graph highlighted in red. Is there an automatic way to achieve this?

Comment: You can achieve that by setting the interpolation to Bezier.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Bezier

You have probably hidden handles ... so just go to *View menu >* **Show Handles** and adjust as needed.

[image]

You can also change **Handle Type** <kbd>V</kbd> to change behaviour like here set **Free** ...

[image]

---

### Easing (by strength)

To work without handles and to use easing, you would have to add a middle key. For the first key switch interpolation <kbd>T</kbd> like to **Circular > Easy Out** ...

[image]

... and for middle one key **Circular > Easy In** under properties side panel <kbd>N</kbd>

[image]

For more info about F-curves see [Blender Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/graph_editor/fcurves/introduction.html)

Comment: I was trying this with a cubic Generator > Expanded Exponential modifier. But I can't find a way to offset the x input (the frame) ? it's always centred on frame 0? I feel I must have missed something.. that seems not very useful.

Comment: I hope your Q is given to public, because you know me ... any math over Add, Multi, Sub, ... is over my capabilities :)

Comment: I'll post it :)